# How to δ > 0 in this LIMIT problem (problem in the link below)?

Tags: calculus, limits

It is probably an easy solution to this problem but I am either too overwhelmed already or not smart enough. Please help me out with this problem from the last year test

[Here is the problem](https://i.stack.imgur.com/rzQWv.jpg)

Comment: Just try picking random values of $\delta$ and see what happens. Observe some patterns.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You want to find a positive number $\delta > 0$ so that if the distance of the point $x$ is less than $\delta$ from 2, then $|f(x) - 1/2| < 1/4$. Recall that $f(x)$ is defined to be $1/x$, so we want that $|1/x - 1/2| < 1/4$.

One possible choice of $\delta$ is say, $\delta = 0.1$. Then if $1.9 < x < 2.1$, we have that $|\frac{1}{1.9} - \frac{1}{2}| < 1/4$ as well as $|\frac{1}{2.1} - \frac{1}{2}| < 1/4$. See if you can find other values of $\delta$ that also make this true.

Answer (score 0):

A bit more general:

For every $\epsilon \gt 0$ there exists a $\delta \gt 0$ such that

$ | 1/x - 1/2| \lt \epsilon$ if $| x -2 | \lt \delta$.

The $\epsilon$ term:

$|1/x - 1/2| = \frac{|x - 2|}{|2x|} \lt \epsilon$.

Need to find a bound for $ |x|$ :

Let's consider $x$ with: $| x - 2| \lt 1$.
Then $1 \lt x $.

Choose $\delta$:

$\delta = \min (1, 2\epsilon)$.

$|1/x - 1/2| = \frac{|x -2|}{|2x|} \lt \frac{|x-2|}{2} \lt \epsilon$.